# subscribe to facebook comment's notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a site, where you can create items. Each item will have it's own facebook comments box.

I need that the user (who is registered with facebook), gets notified when a new comment arrive just as if he had commented on that particular comment box i.e. Inside facebook.com, the user should see the "red world" icon.

Can I achieve this?